# Clicking on the smart object opens a new blank photoshop window instead of the file contents

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

So, everything was working fine until I reset my Photoshop preferences and all of a sudden whenever I click on a smart object to edit it I get a "New Photoshop window" thing. Same thing happens when I click on Edit contents while the smart object is selected.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Smart Objects do open into a new window. What happens if you make a new document with a new smart object, place something in the smart object, save it and then re-open that new smart object. Does that work?

Comment: That's the normal behaviour when opening a smart object to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

It is standard behavior that a new window opens when editing a smart object - either via a double-click in the Layers Panel or by choosing `Edit Contents`.

The window opens. You edit the contents of the Smart Object. Save. Then close the window. The primary document's smart object layer, then updates to reflect the changes you made.

If this is the behavior you are experiencing, there is no issue. If this is *not* the behavior you are experiencing, a more detailed description of your problem may be necessary.